# Set HttpContext.Current.Application from Console Application

Tags: asp.net, console-application

I'm in process of creating a Console Application, which needs to invode methods that heavily dependent on HttpContext. I could simulate the base HttpContext as well as the authentication, but I fail to set HttpContext.Current.Application. Is there any possibility to set the data in it?

There were couple of question on the same subject overe here, but couldn't get a solution from either, and thus ended up posting another one here.

My target is to get this working.

```
HttpContext.Current.Application("PageDefinitionCache") = pageDefinitions
```

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache lives inside the ASP.NET worker process, you cannot access it directly from a console application. `HttpContext.Current` is `null` since you don't use the aspx.net worker process in a console application.

Consider declaring a global variable in the console application to simulate the behavior of the `HttpContext.Current.Application`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry that I've not given attention to tihs for long. As the same code base been used for Web architecture as well, I cannot re-write or simulate Application object. So I've solved my issue by populating required object's data again in case it's found to be 'NULL'. This way, I could make the same code working well for both architectures.

Comment: Now when we've to implement similar application again, we implemented by having an Interface and implementing it to use 'HttpContext.Current.Application' for Web Application and use a global variable for Console Application so that the common code can remain common.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use HttpContext in Console application.
as mentioned by @matrxRapture you can resolve this issue by using global variables and if you are looking for current directory path for the application you can use **Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location**